# ArangoDB 2.8 database.exists(fieldValue)? I need to check if exists by field value

Tags: arangodb

Using arango **2.8** db I can check if a document exist based on its id. But can I check if any document exists given a value for a field.

```
//if any document in database exist where fieldX = X return true
if(repoName.exists({fieldX:"X"})){
  //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found what I needed: `byExample()`

```
repoName.byExample({fieldX:"X"})
```